# Connect to an unsecured WebSocket over https

Tags: javascript, https, websocket

I am trying to establish a connection to a unsecured WebSocket.

However, my page is loaded over HTTPS, which means the browser won't allow an unsecure WS connection, instead it will require a secure WSS connection.

Is there any workaround to connect to an unsecured WebSocket when loading my page over HTTPS?

The JS code is simple:

```
<script>

var wsUri = "ws://201.77.219.223/ws";
websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
websocket.onopen = function(evt) {
console.log("Connected to Endpoint!");
};
websocket.onmessage = function(evt) {
console.log("Message Received: " + evt.data);
};
websocket.onerror = function(evt) {
console.log("ERROR: " + evt.data);
};
function doSend(message) {
console.log("Message Sent: " + message);
websocket.send(message);
}
doSend({
"module": "login",
"service": "authentication",
"parameters": {"login": "teste", "password": "123456"}
} );

</script>
```

Comment: You already answered your own question: "*the browser won't allow it*", so NO, there is no workaround. If an HTML page is served over HTTPS, any WebSocket connections it makes MUST use WSS only. Chrome used to have an "Allow insecure WebSocket from https origin" option, but that was intentionally removed a couple of years ago.

Comment: Is possible to use a proxy to change this behavior? I am not owner of the websocket so I can't secure it. At the same time I can't downgrade my site to http.

Comment: [How HTML5 Web Sockets Interact With Proxy Servers](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Web-Sockets-Proxy-Servers). You would need a WebSocket proxy that can accept secure WSS connections and forward them to unsecure WS servers. There might be something floating around for that, or you might have to write your own to suit your needs.